# overloading operators == and != : compiler moans ambiguity

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, conditional-operator

I have the following code:

```
bool operator==(const Inc::CReminderItem& Item1, const Inc::CReminderItem& Item2)
{
    bool bDate = false, bDesc = false, bInfo = false, bWeekday = false;

    if(Item1.m_Date == Item2.m_Date)
        bDate = true;
    if(Item1.m_strDescription == Item2.m_strDescription)
        bDesc = true;
    if(Item1.m_strInfoShort == Item2.m_strInfoShort)
        bInfo = true;
    if(Item1.m_nWeekday == Item2.m_nWeekday)
        bWeekday = true;

    return(bDate && bDesc && bInfo && bWeekday);
}

bool operator!=(const Inc::CReminderItem& Item1, const Inc::CReminderItem& Item2)
{
    return !(Item1 == Item2);    // <<--- ambiguous here!
}
```

both operators are declared as friend operators in the class.

the error is:

> error C2593: 'operator ==' is
>   ambiguous

I am not sure, why it is ambiguous O_o and how to fix this.
Any help is greatly appreciated:)

Comment: The compiler should tell you something like *possible candidates are...*. Otherwise, maybe there exists a member-function, or you have some implicit conversions for `CReminderItem`?

Comment: Does it say which are the possible candidates which are causing ambiguity?

Comment: there are neither possible candidates, nor should there be any imlicit conversions (visual studio 2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if it is "ambiguous", I would expect other `operator==` to be
present somewhere.  But it's hard to say what any particular compiler is
really trying to tell you with it's error messages.

Second, you really don't show enough code for anyone to say what is
wrong.  There are a number of possible errors: the class where the
friend is declared and these definitions are in different namespaces,
the signature of the friend is subtly different, etc.  If `Inc` is
a namespace, these operators must be in `Inc` as well.  Otherwise,
you've declared an `operator==` in `Inc` in the friend declaration, and
an `operator==` in global namespace here.  Both are considered, which
results in an ambiguity.

(The way I usually handle this is to define a member function,
`isEqual`, and have both `operator==` and `operator!=` call it.  That
way, there's no need for the friend declaration.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have defined a `operator==` within the class scope like

```
class CReminderItem {
public:
    bool operator==(CReminderItem const&) const;
};
```

That is ambiguous with the global operator overload.

Comment: -o - my fault. a declaration is enough for compile to moan such an error. I'm wondering why compile consider that as ambiguous, not redefinition.

Comment: Because `bool operator==(CReminderItem const&) const` is not the same as `bool CReminderItem::operator==(CReminderItem const&) const`?